# Prevent counter from incrementing again if user has guessed

Tags: javascript

I have created a small app that has a `button` that plays a different sound each time the user clicks it and if they guess the correct animal the score counter goes up.

However if he presses `enter` a couple of times the counter still scores and that enables him to cheat.

How can I make so that if he has guessed, the counter increments with one but if he presses enter again and they guessed the sound the counter stays the same? I tried with a boolean value like the isEntered logic but it did not work, I tried enclosing the shuffle logic in a function and call it each time he has guessed but that did not yield the desired result, here is my code:

```
var sounds = [
  {
    animalType: 'horse',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Horse-neigh.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'bear',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/grizzlybear.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'goat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Goat-noise.mp3'),
  },
  {
    animalType: 'cat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/cat.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'dog',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/dog-bark.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'sheep',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/sheep.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'rooster',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/rooster.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'lion',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/lion.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'hen',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/hen.mp3')
  }
]

var player = document.getElementById('player');
var enteredWord = document.getElementById('entered-word');
var counter = document.getElementById('counter-score');
var errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
var wrongAnswerSound = new Audio('../sounds/Wrong-answer-sound-effect.mp3');
var isEntered = false;

function startGame() {
  var currentSound;
    player.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
    currentSound = sound.animalType;
    sound['sound'].play();
  })

  enteredWord.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
      if(enteredWord.value.toLowerCase() === currentSound) {
        isEntered = true;
        counter.textContent ++;
        errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
        enteredWord.classList.remove('input-error-border');
      } else {
        isEntered = false;
        errorMessage.style.display = 'inline-block';
        enteredWord.classList.add('input-error-border');
        wrongAnswerSound.play();
      }  
    } 
  })
}

startGame();
```

and my html:

```
<div class="help">
      <p class="question-mark trigger">?</p>
      <div class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
             <h1> Click on the note icon to hear a sound, then try to guess it by typing the animals name.</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
    <div id="player"><img src="../images/note.png"></div>
      <input type="text" autofocus id="entered-word" placeholder="Guess the animal sound" >
    </div>
    <div id="counter">Score:<span id="counter-score"> 0</span> </div>
```

Comment: post html and js too

Comment: You never use `isEntered` anywhere.

Comment: I updated my question with the html

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `isEntered` variable in the event listener, like this:

```
enteredWord.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if(event.key === 'Enter') {
    if(enteredWord.value.toLowerCase() === currentSound && isEntered === false) {
      isEntered = true;
      counter.textContent ++;
      errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
      enteredWord.classList.remove('input-error-border');
    } else {
      isEntered = false;
      errorMessage.style.display = 'inline-block';
      enteredWord.classList.add('input-error-border');
      wrongAnswerSound.play();
    }  
  } 
})
```

Comment: it gives me that isEntered is not defined and the counter stopped working

Comment: There was a typo in what I wrote if you just copied/pasted. It should work now.